# Requesting HTTPS and submitting forms in Java

Tags: java, javascript, submit, httprequest

I got the following scenario:
On my webserver I have a .do file with HTML code like this:

```
<form name="login" action="someAction" method="post">
    //some textboxes
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Now I'm trying to make an application, which connects to the webserver - https - fills out the form and get the HTML from the next site (the site, when you're logged in).
After that I have to do several JavaScript submits to get the data I want to display it in my desktop application.

I somehow managed to build a connection and get the HTML from the login site, but since I'm new to HttpRequests and stuff like that, I have no idea how to go on.

Help would be appreciated.

Edit: I get the following in my Console:

```
Sep 24, 2011 2:23:28 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Sep 24, 2011 2:23:30 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Error: ERROR: No matching script interactive for function () {
    var result = bootstrapDojo();
    result.dojo._dijit = result.dijit;
    result.dojo._dojox = result.dojox;
    return result.dojo;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/):

> HtmlUnit is a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs". It models HTML
>   documents and provides an API that allows you to invoke pages, fill
>   out forms, click links, etc... just like you do in your "normal"
>   browser.
>
> It has fairly good JavaScript support (which is constantly improving)
>   and is able to work even with quite complex AJAX libraries, simulating
>   either Firefox or Internet Explorer depending on the configuration you
>   want to use.
>
> It is typically used for testing purposes or to retrieve information
>   from web sites.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot!
However, I'm running into an error after clicking on a submit button of a form (see first post)